# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported when start wireguard

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, vpn

when I using this command to start wireguard:

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release https://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install yum-plugin-elrepo
$ sudo yum install kmod-wireguard wireguard-tools
$ wg-quick up wg0
```

the result:

```
Warning: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' is world accessible
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
Cannot find device "wg0"
```

this is my kernel version:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz wireguard]# uname -r
4.4.219-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

I just do not known where is the problem?

```
yum install kmod-wireguard
Package kmod-wireguard-1.0.20200413-1.el7_7.elrepo.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Linux kernel 5.6 has wireguard, otherwise you should use dkms wireguard, since you are on 4.4

Comment: I follow the official doc to install it.How to using dkms?

Comment: Now you added that you installed the part intended for the kernel module. So if it doesn't work, that means it failed somehow when installing kmod-wireguard. You're supposed to have inherited the wireguard module. It should be somewhere in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/ as wireguard.ko

Comment: I upgrade my kernel to 5.6 and solved it.